# void initState() Flutter and php don't work

Tags: php, flutter

I have developed an app in which I log in to access.

But after accessing, it doesn't work and I cannot see the name and surname of the person who is logged in.

This is the code:

FLUTTER WIDGET:

```
initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }


void getData() async {

    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    code = prefs.getString('code');

    var url = "http://localhost/profilo.php";

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      "username": code,
    });

    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    nomecognome = "WELCOME "+ data['name'] +" "+ data['surname'];

    print(nomecognome);

  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
        child: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget> [
              SizedBox(height: 50,),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(nomecognome ?? "", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 20),),
                  )
              ),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {
                esciLogout();
              },
                child: Text("LOGOUT",
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "NovareseStd",
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

PHP Server code:

```
<?php

$queryCheck = "SELECT *  FROM utents WHERE username='". strtolower($_REQUEST['username']) ."'";
    $selectCheck = mysqli_query($connessione, $queryCheck);
    
    $result = array();

    $resultCheck = mysqli_fetch_array($selectCheck);
        
    $result['name'] = $resultCheck['name'];
    
    $result['surname'] = $resultCheck['surname'];

    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

When I run the code, I can see the output on terminal `flutter: WELCOME DEMO HARVEY` but I don't understand why `child: Text(nomecognome)` doesn't show on screen?

What did I do wrong?
Or is something missing?

Thank you very much

I want that when I login, when it is succesful, next page must appear "WELCOME DEMO HARVEY" on TEXT.

Comment: I'm sorry but your english is really poor and it's hard to understand what you are saying. Also, I don't mean it in an impolite way. Could you try to maybe improve the question as it is hard to answer without understanding.

Comment: Forgive me, I speak little English but I try to improve myself....my question is the code that you have see, I want that when i log using username and passowrd, I log, go a page with a simple text the my name and surname, meaning what after enter on page is write WELCOME DEMO HARVEY

Comment: Quindi, vuoi dire che nel terminale viene mostrato DEMO DI BENVENUTO HARVEY ma non viene mostrato nel widget di testo. For those in English: So, you mean that in terminal WELCOME DEMO HARVEY is shown but it is not showing in text widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getDate function you should call setState((){}) to let flutter know that it should rebuild the widget.
Here's the updated solution:

```
void getData() async {

    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    code = prefs.getString('code');

    var url = "http://localhost/profilo.php";

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      "username": code,
    });

    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    nomecognome = "WELCOME "+ data['name'] +" "+ data['surname'];
    setState((){}); //Add this line
    print(nomecognome);

  }
```

Comment: GREAT!!!! WORK!!!! Thank you very much :D